# Creating a new 3rd party program for a game

Tags: online-game

So I am trying to make a program like STO Keyibds, https://sourceforge.net/projects/sto-keybind/, but for Linux. STO Keybinds won't work and I want to build my programming skills and want to make this kind of program on my own. My issue is that I am trying to figure out where I can get a platform similar to the one in the link. I would need drop down boxes, and more. Is anyone able to help?